# Python Mailing timed out error

Tags: python, mailing

I cannot send an email from python. Probably there is a security issue. Can somebody give me a hint?
This is the code:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

server.starttls()

#Next, log in to the server
server.login("***@gmail.com", "PASSWORD")

#Send the mail
msg = "Hello!"
# The /n separates the message from the headers
server.sendmail("***@gmail.com", "***@gmail.com", msg)
server.quit()
```

This is the error I get:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
File "D:\Tools\Lib\smtplib.py", line 244, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "D:\Tools\Lib\smtplib.py", line 310, in connect
    raise socket.error, msg
  error: (10060, 'Operation timed out')
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use smtplib.SMTP_SSL() because port 587 expects ssl(tls) from the get go.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL

Answer (score 0):

check with gmail sometimes gmail blocks the signing from apps

[image]

Comment: This would cause failures that would return an error, he may still need to do this but it's not what caused this particular error.